# Same font from google and fontsquirrel appears differently

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I use the font Montserrat on my website. I normally use the one from Google Fonts available [here](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Montserrat). It has only two styles available: `normal` and `bold`.

I recently discovered that there exist two other styles for this font, available on [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat): `hairline` and `light`. I would need these two too and since they are not present on Google Fonts I thought to download them from Font Squirrel and then use their webfont generator.

I noticed, though, that the same font, with same style and weight, looks slightly different. Here's a screenshot to compare the bold version:

[image]

On top is the one from Font Squirrel and the other is from Google Fonts. I'm using the same font size and bold. It's evident that besides the slightly different letter spacing also the single letters are different.

When you create a webfont on Font Squirrel there lot of options, but not being an expert it's unclear what they do. Is it possible that they could make the font to look the same as the Google one?

Answer (score 0):

FontSquirrel is mostly about hosting and webfont conversion, so if it has a font that looks wrong, that's something they'll need to fix. In terms of "which one is right", so that we know whether fontsquirrel is wrong, or google fonts is wrong, it's trivial to find this font's author and real project page: http://montserrat.zkysky.com.ar/en

On the font's own website, the font's creator links to the Google webfont version as the "download the font" option, so we can safely assume that's the typeface they intended for people to use.

Of course where FontSquirrel then got the other font faces from is a mystery you should probably ask them about, and get them to change, since they're clearly *not* serving the right font.

Comment: Well, I never said "better letter spacing", so I'm not sure what you are quoting. I said that they look different and that I prefer anyway the version on google font. My question was mainly if was it possible that the options present on Font Squirrel to create a webfont could make the font to look like the one on Google Font.
Besides this, I was aware of the project page, but that was beyond the point of my question.

Comment: misread you there, but the other points still hold - font squirrel is not in the business of "making one font look like another", they simply host and convert fonts, so in this case, somehow, what they're serving is *not* the true font, and you probably want to notify them of that.